# Manifolds with boundary and foliations

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, foliations

Is there a theory of foliations by manifolds with boundary? Particularly, Is there a generalization of the Frobenius theorem and the Stefan-Sussmann theorem in which the leaves are manifolds with boundary?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: One reasonable guess is that you can assume each component of the boundary to be a leave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you assume appropriate boundary conditions, everything is the same as in the theory without boundary.

[This preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.04845) and [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.12970) give Frobenius and Stefan-Sussmann type theorems for manifolds with boundary assuming the distribution is **normal:** there is a vector in the distribution transverse to the boundary at each point. It is precisely this situation where the leaves have boundary.